# Jekyll : New posts not being generated

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am setting up a jekyll blog. I put the .md files in the _posts folder. run `jekyll --server` command in the root of the project directory.
But jekyll just regenerates the older posts, the news posts are not being added to _site.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found why jekyll was failing. The title i used in one of my posts had a colon (:) in it. I just had to replace it with `&#58;` and the post parsed fine.