# Jekyll turning page titles into ordered lists on GitHub Pages

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have added headers to each of my markdown pages on GitHub Pages, and am having troubles getting the following example to display correctly:

```
---
layout: default 
title: 1222.01 PLAN ADOPTED.
---

{{ page.title }}
----------------
```

When Jekyll converts the markdown into HTML, the result looks like this:

> 1. 01 PLAN ADOPTED.

This seems to be happening repeatedly regardless of the number which proceeds the first period in the title, but doesn't seem to have any issue with the second period at the end. Also, this only seems to be happening with page titles that contain periods, as I'm not experiencing any issues with the other page titles (without periods).

Any idea how I might correct this?

Comment: As an aside, this is a known problem with markdown, even described on Gruber's page: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the title into double quotes:

```
title: "1222.01 PLAN ADOPTED."
```

Comment: Thanks Polygnome, I've added the quotes to my markdown but the page title is still [displaying as an ordered list](http://christopherritter.github.io/springboro-ordinances/md/46abcf2f.html). Here's [the source](https://github.com/christopherritter/springboro-ordinances/blob/gh-pages/md/46abcf2f.md).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963002/jekyll-new-posts-not-being-generated) where the colon in the title was causing issues with Jekyll. After replacing the periods with `&#46;` the page title worked fine.