# How to put colon in a Jekyll/Kramdown post title?

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

The title of my Jekyll/Kramdown post contains a colon

```
---
layout: post
title: abc : def
---
```

and the page fails to generate. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963002/jekyll-new-posts-not-being-generated), I should replace the colon by `&#58;`, so I did that. In the preview on Github it showed correctly as a colon, but in the actual post it just showed `&#58;`. What might be the fix here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. I just wrote

```
title: "abc : def"
```